# Is there a way to go backward and forward in chrome developer tool when debugging javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Just like `Ctrl+o` and `Ctrl+i` vim, I would like to jump backward and forward in chrome developer tool when debugging javascript, because when I jumped to a new position to see the definition of a function, it took me a long time to find the previous cursor position. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean with forward / backward? In the page history (breaking in a breakpoint after navigation to a new page/anchor, want: to navigate to the previous anchor/page?), in the call history/order (run into breakpoint 1, continue, run into breakpoint 2, want: to step back to BP #1?) or in the call hierarchy (stack, breaking at BP in `foo()`; want: go to `bar()`, which called `foo()`)? Please clarify - edit your post.